# GOES-16 off-Nadir resolution calculation

Tags: resolution, goes-16

I am using GOES-16 ABI. GOES-16 is located on 0 lat. and 75.2 W.

The nadir resolution of bands that I am using is 2 kilometers. I need to calculate resolution of the pixels at a given latitude & longitude. How to do that?

Comment: Hi - welcome to StackGIS - please have a read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Specifically we would be looking for what you have tried already